# D3 JS tooltips fire mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I have made a slightly modified bar chart to add an extra bar over the top of the original data when the value of the bar goes over a target value. This is just so that I can change the colour of the bar to red.

Now I'm trying to fire the mouseover event on the original bar when the red one is hovered over, but the event doesn't seem to fire properly. If I change the CSS on the bar or try to read data from it, it works fine.

Mouseover event like so:

```
$('#chart-canvas').on('mouseover', '.over-target', function() {
var xBar = $(this).attr('x');
$('#chart-canvas').find('.bar:not(.over-target)[x="'+xBar+'"]').trigger('mouseover');
```

});

Here's a JSfiddle of what I have http://jsfiddle.net/6LCdW/11/

Alternatively, is there a way I can remove the overlapping red bar and just change the colour at the top of the blue bars where necessary?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: you set `pointer-events: none;` for the overlapping bars.

A couple of additional comments on your code though. First, I would advise against mixing D3 and JQuery unless you absolutely need to -- it avoids much confusion later on.

Second, the D3 way of adding those overlapping bars would be to not add them one by one, but rather filter the data that adds them. That is, the code to add them would become

```
svg.selectAll(".bar.over-target")
   .data(data.filter(function(d) { return +d.value > +d.target; }))
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar over-target")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); 
   .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
   .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
   .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.target) - y(d.value); });
```

No explicit loop or conditional statement needed anymore. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6LCdW/12/).

To answer your second question, you can do this with a single `rect` if you're filling it with a [gradient](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_grad_linear.asp) that has two stops at the same position to effect a sudden change in color.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks Lars. Are there any advantages over using either the loop above or a gradient?

Comment: IMHO the code above is more intuitive than the loop/condition. The advantage of a gradient is that you wouldn't need a separate element, but it would make the code a bit messier.

Comment: OK I'll stick with what I've got then. Thanks again